# exchange circle pixels in an image in matlab

Tags: arrays, image, matlab, geometry

All I want is to add a circle into an image of a radius and centre of my choice, however I DO NOT WANT to use plot COMMAND, I want a new output array which has my chosen image and circle on it.
here is my function

`function [ out_image ] = draw_circle( in_image,x0,y0,r,value)`

where in_image is the input image
x0 y0 he centre of circle and r the radius
value the intensity of image

this is my attempt which does not work

```
ang=0:pi/100:2*pi
x=r*cos(ang)+x0;
y=r*sin(ang)+y0;
cir=[x,y];
[j,k]=size(cir);
for cir=1:j
    for cir=1:k     
if cir(i,j)==0
out_image(i,j)=in_image(i,j);
end
end
end

imshow(out_image)

end
```

Comment: closed circle or just the outline?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure there are better ways, but following your approach, you might use the following code:

```
out_image = in_image;
cir = round([r*cos(ang)+x0;r*sin(ang)+y0]);
for i = 1:size(cir,2)
    out_image(cir(1,i),cir(2,i),:) = 255;
end
```

Your for loops did not work the way you wrote them. Also, you should use round to get indices, and not floating point values. However, the circle is quite small (only 1 pixel), which might not be enough for large pictures. See example below. Also, you might need a finer discritization for large pictures, i.e. a larger number of elements in `ang`. [image]

In case you want a larger **linewidth**, you can use

```
lw = 3; % Enter linewidth here
for i = 1:size(cir,2)
    out_image(cir(1,i)+(-lw:lw),cir(2,i)+(-lw:lw),:) = 255;
end
```

[image]
EDIT: In case you don't see it. The circle is close to the top left corner.

The complete code for the function is:

```
function [ out_image ] = draw_circle( in_image,x0,y0,r,value,lw)

out_image = in_image;
ang = 0:pi/100:2*pi;
cir = round([r*cos(ang)+x0;r*sin(ang)+y0]);
for i = 1:size(cir,2)
    out_image(cir(1,i)+(-lw:lw),cir(2,i)+(-lw:lw),:) = value;
end
imshow(out_image)
```

You can call it from command line with

```
draw_circle(in_image,100,200,50,0,3);
```

Note, I took the unused `value` as grayscale value.

Comment: Well, I was a bit lazy and replaced `out_image` by `out` in my code. It is now correct, also with initialization.

Comment: ang=0:pi/100:2*pi; 
                                                           x=r*cos(ang)+x0;
                                                         y=r*sin(ang)+y0;
                                        cir=round([r*cos(ang)+x0;r*sin(ang)+y0]);
                                                                 for cir=i=1:size(cir,2);
                                          out_image(cir(1,i),cir(2,i),:)=255;
                                                                 end

Comment: The `for` loop is not correct. You use `for cir=i=1:size(cir,2);` but it is `for i=1:size(cir,2)` in my code. Also, you can remove `x=...` and `y=...`. I uploaded the complete code. You can copy it.

Comment: Sir thank you very much, you have helped me a lot, you are a great person who has chosen to share his knowledge.